# Alpine on Linode looses it's IP after reboot

Tags: iptables, ip, linode

I am trying to install an alpine server on a linode computer.

Here is a tutorial from linode to show how to install alpine on their hosts, I've done that so often, that I wrote a script which supports me, to do this in less than 2minutes:

https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/custom-kernels-distros/install-alpine-linux-on-your-linode

Here is my script

https://github.com/exocode/alpine-linode-bootstrap/

after a reboot into this new Alpine I've done that:

Here is my whole history

```
0 clear
1 cat /etc/network/interfaces
2 apk add iptables
3 rc-update add iptables boot
4 apk add iptables-persistent
5 iptables save
6 /etc/init.d/iptables save
7 service iptables save
8 service networking restart
9 cat /etc/network/interfaces
10 ping -c 2 google.com
11 passwd
12 adduser example-user
13 edituser example-user
14 deluser example-user
15 cat /etc/group
16 adduser example-user
17 apk add sudo
18 echo "%sudo   ALL=(ALL) ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
19 addgroup sudo
20 adduser example-user sudo
21 mkdir -p ~/.ssh && chmod -R 700 ~/.ssh/
22 setup-sshd
23 vi /etc/apk/repositories
24 apk update
25 apk add docker
26 rc-update add docker boot
27 iptables -L
28 cat /etc/network/interfaces
29 iptables -L
30 service docker start
31 iptables -L
32 cat /etc/network/interfaces
33
34 service -l
35 service networking restart
36 cat /etc/network/interfaces
37 iptables -L
38 ip addr
39 service networking restart
40 setup-interfaces
41 service networking restart
42 cat /etc/network/interfaces
43 history
44 clear
45  cat /etc/network/interfaces
46 ip addr
47 clear
48 histo
49 history
```

Infos of /interfaces and iptables

```
alpine:~#  cat /etc/network/interfaces

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto docker0
iface docker0 inet static
        address 172.17.0.1
        netmask 255.255.0.0

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
        hostname alpine



alpine:~# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK> mtu 65536 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether f2:3c:91:e7:38:9c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet _139.162.1.56/24 brd 139.162.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2400:8901::f03c:91ff:fee7:389c/64 scope global dynamic
       valid_lft 2591996sec preferred_lft 604796sec
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN
    link/ether 02:42:16:3e:75:48 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**My goal**

__ is to have a docker app running on linode__

**MY PROBLEM**

If I reboot my linode after the successfull alpine installation, and doing another reboot my eth0 IP is gone!

How can I restart my server without loosing the ip settings:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether f2:3c:91:e7:38:9c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Are you sure that your Alpine linux boot not into Rescue Mode?

Comment: yes, sure... If I run "rc-service networking restart" the "ip addr" lists my eth0 WITH IP